# How to create custom rule event

Tags: rules

I'm working on integration of my D7 module with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules). I have custom SQL table with 2 columns `node_id` and `status`. `Status` may have values 0, 1, 2, 3. How can I create event with `hook_rules_event_info` to react on status change? I.e. status changed from `0` to `1` -> send email to node owner.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a formal drupal node you can use node update event , then check if the node->status is changed or not (you have 2 versions of node in this event one referring to unchanged and second refers to changed noge)